# How to make the width of the border the same after scaling？

Tags: ios, swift, border, scaling

**I set "borderwidth = 3" to the view. After I scaling, the border either became thicker or thinner.**

before scaling (yellow border on the left photo)
after scaling( yellow border on the right photo)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJB21.png)

**How can I keep the width of the border fixed after I scale it?**

I user this source on the GitHub
https://github.com/yokurin/DragRotateScaleView

And just add `v.layer.borderWidth = 5`

```
lazy var rect1: DragRotateScaleView = {
        let v = DragRotateScaleView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200))
        v.delegate = self
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        v.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 22/255, green:  22/255, blue:  22/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
        v.layer.borderWidth = 5
        return v
    }()
```

**Thank You!!**

Comment: Show the code, it seems to me that you are not correct working with view. 
I need the code how you setting border width, and how scaling. Is it going in the same class?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already updated my post.

Comment: Ok, and how you scaling it? In the same class?

Comment: Which delegate methods are you using for scaling the view?

Comment: Yes, in the same class

Comment: In fact, if you are using that git, you are walked in the wrong way. Your view size must be setted by constraints, and all moving must be in changing constraints values, so all borders will stay with the same size. If you are changing the view directly - the border width will be changed too. 
Try to read this for example:
https://www.zerotoappstore.com/pinch-to-zoom-images-swift-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

Just **divide the border width by the scale** and set that value to the `borderWidth` again.

Try this in a playground:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

// Save this values, you will use them.
let border: CGFloat = 3
let scale: CGFloat = 5

// Example views.
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
view.backgroundColor = .red
let secondView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
secondView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
secondView.layer.borderWidth = border
view.addSubview(secondView)

// View scale transformation.
secondView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)

// IMPORTANT: Change the width of the border after the transformation.
secondView.layer.borderWidth = border / scale

// This is only for the playground.
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```